# Graph theory proving question on connected graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two vertex disjoint (that is $V(G_1)\cap V(G_2) = \emptyset$) connected graphs of order at least $2$. Let $H = G_1 + G_2$. Prove that $\text{Cen}(H)$ is always a connected graph.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I assume that $G_1 + G_2$ is the join formed by adding all edges between the graphs? And that $\text{Cen}(H)$ is the center of $H$?

Comment: Ah yes! G1 + G2 is to join the edges between all vertexes of G1 and G2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Case 1: For $i=1,2$ no vertex of $G_i$ is adjacent to every other vertex of $G_i$.

Case 2: For $i=1,2$, some vertex of $G_i$ is adjacent to every other vertex of $G_i$.

Case 3: For  $i=1$ or $2$ no vertex of $G_i$ is adjacent to every other vertex of $G_i$, but for $j=1$ or $2$ some vertex of $G_j$ is adjacent to every other vertex of $G_j$.

In all cases note that the distance between two vertices is at most $2$, as you can get from one to the other by going to a vertex in the other graph, and (if necessary) back.